# Как переписать строку в SQL базу  в C#?

Tags: sql, c#

Как переписать строку в SQL базу в C#? Мне нужно переносить на строку другое значение, 
добавить получается

```
gioDataSet.Tables["raodenoba"].Rows.Add(int.Parse(label2.Text.ToString()),3);
```

А переписать нет. Подскажите, как сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
gioDataSet.Tables["raodenoba"].Rows[0]["column"] = "new value for column";
```

Полное описание есть на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc(v=vs.71).aspx)